# How to save form data in google spreadsheet using angular 2 http.post()

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to save the form data in spreadsheet using http.post() using angular 2.I have been successful in getting the spreadsheet data using http.get() but how do I save the data to spreadsheet using http.post().What url of my spreadsheet should I pass in the post()?Do I have to pass the same url that I passed to get() that gave me JSON response or something else I need to do.....

Answer (score 1):

You can use `http.post` with the same url. It's a recommended way to build Rest API services

```
GET /items      //get items
POST /items     //save item
```

there are 2 different requests for backend